# Which hand should you hold your phone in when playing Just Dance Now?

Tags: just-dance-now

It says on the screen, very clearly, that you should hold the phone in your right hand. However, I noticed getting more points when holding it in my left hand. Also, the screen-dancer's left hand is usually highlighted. Now I'm confused.

The only video I found of people dancing with their phones in their hands is [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mdM2iGriiY), but I don't know if that's really their left hand or their right hand.

Moreover, do I do with my left hand what the screen-dancer does with her right hand, or opposite? There are some instructions but I don't get them.

*The whole mirror thing is confusing me.*

Is there a simple way to think about this?

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvote?

Comment: This seems to have been flagged as "opinion-based". I disagree, but that my explain the downvote.

Comment: Yeah, the system warned me that my question is probably opinion based when I typed in the title. Someone might have been relying on some automatic classification without really reading the question. Anyway, thanks for the info!

Comment: Because I do not see this question as being useful. Are you right handed? Hold it in your right hand. Left handed? Change hands. How could a phone know what you are doing with the opposite hand? Some of this is just common sense.

Comment: @Timelord64: Are you familiar with how the game is played? You hold the phone in your hand and then dance, the phone detects your motions, which are different for left/right hand.

Comment: Also, its pretty obvious to me that those people are using their left hands. You could also test this easily,by playing a song left handed,and repeating right handed, if it makes as much of a difference as you say.

Comment: @Timelord64: I also thought it was obvious, but then I looked myself in the mirror and realised that my hands are reversed and got confused. Also, I got more points with my left hand, but the instructions say you should use your right hand... That's a pretty big mistake, so I thought they would have corrected it by now. So I thought maybe I should hold it in my right hand but swing my hands left where I was swinging them right, or something like that.

Comment: So to confirm, you get more points with your left hand, you are told **visually** to use your left hand, the youtube videos display using the left hand.. theres your answer.

Comment: I'm not visually told to use my left hand. The dancer is holding it in what looks like her left hand, but that would be my right hand if I have to dance like I'm an image of her in the mirror (the instructions mention something like that). I'd just like an answer from someone who gets top scores in the game and knows for sure. I'm obviously confused and you haven't played the game, so I don't think that the two of us can come to a conclusion.

Answer (score -1):

The console versions of the game specify to hold the controller in your right hand, and to treat the display as a mirror. (i.e., your right hand should mirror the Just Dancer's left hand). There's actually a tutorial popup that displays this in Just Dance 2015, but my google-fu hasn't returned a screen cap.

My best guess would be that they would not have changed this for Just Dance Now, and any anecdote of scoring higher with the left hand is a combination of imprecise movement detection, memory and confirmation biases, or both.